# Show that there does not exist a group homomorphism from G onto G'

Tags: group-isomorphism

Show that there does not exist a group homomorphism from G onto G', where G and G' are groups of order 9 and 6 respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, any group of even order, like $G'$, has a element of order $2$. Show that this can't be in the image of $G$ for any homomorphism.

If $\phi(g)^2=1_{G'}$ in $G'$, then $1_{G'}=\phi(1_G)=\phi(g^9)=\phi(g)^8\cdot \phi(g)= \phi(g)$.

Comment: Also, if f(a) is the element of order 2, I'm guessing I must show that o(f(a)) cannot be a divisor of o(a), since o(a) can only attain the values, 1,3 and 9. Am I correct?

Comment: You've assumed that g^9=eG, but the order of G is also 9. Wouldn't that make G cyclic? And that isn't mentioned in the problem

Comment: No, $g^{|G|}=e_G$ for all $g\in G$, for any finite group $G$. @thedas

Comment: I beg to differ, taking the symmetric group s3 as an example, it's clear that (rho5)^6 is not equal to rho0.

Answer (score 1):

For any homomorphism between finite groups, the elements that are hit are all hit equally many times. In this case that would mean $1.5$ times, which is absurd.

Comment: How would I write it down as a formal proof?

Comment: That's up to you - consider the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: Hmm, so I have to deal with the kernel of this homomorphism

Comment: @thedas Exactly. If the homomorphism is surjective, then the kernel must contain $1.5$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the image of a homomorphism between finite groups must divide the order of the domain but $6$ does not divide $9$.